# Обновление AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Помогите разобраться. Есть страница, на ней выводятся блоки. В блоке есть небольшой контент и таймер. Блоки генерируются циклом while. Хочу сделать обновление таймера каждую секунду. Не пойму как мне для каждого блока в исходной странице подобрать данные для нужного блока из файла обработчика? 
Вот код примерный

```
while ($rowpb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querypb)) {

$prod_id = $rowpb['id'];
$querypbc    = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `play_prod` WHERE 
prod_id='$prod_id' AND play_id='$play_id' LIMIT 1");
$rowpbc      = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querypbc);
$countpbc    = mysqli_num_rows($querypbc);

<div class="col-md-12">
          <div>  $rowpbc['чтото']</div>
          <div>  $rowpbc['чтото']</div>
          <div>   Здесь таймер который я хочу обновлять каждую секунду</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div>  $rowpbc['чтото']</div>
  <div>  $rowpbc['чтото']</div>
  <div></div>
  <!-- Здесь таймер который я хочу обновлять каждую секунду -->
  <script>
    (function(){
      var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".col-md-12 > div:nth-child(3)");
      setInterval(function(block){
        // refresh content of block
        var value = +block.textContent;
        value = isNaN(value)? 0 : value + 1;
        block.textContent = value;
      }, 1000, blocks[blocks.length - 1]);
    })();
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Данные по таймеру берутся из базы, разве будет корректное обновление?

Comment: @Артём Да, будет корректное обновление. Если Вы его правильно напишете, конечно.

Comment: что то у меня походу не получается, но вроде правильно написал!

Comment: @Артём кхм, кхм... Вы понимаете, что мне сквозь монитор не видно Вашего кода (походу)?

Comment: ваш весь код скопировал на пустой странице вставил, но ничего не обновляется!

Comment: @Артём Мой код ничего не обновляет. Обновление должны написать Вы - вместо строчки `// refresh content of block`.

Comment: Просто насколько я знаю для обновления элемента на странице нужно использовать ajax. Но я не понимаю как мне вставить нужный таймер в блок из php обработчика

Comment: @Артём Да, нужно использовать ajax. Но это совершенно другой вопрос. Как создать таймер, я Вам показал. Я изменил код, чтобы он каждую секунду обновлял содержимое блока. Задавайте теперь другой вопрос про ajax.

Comment: Дело в том что блоки появляются по циклу и я не знаю как мне вставить в каждый блок своё значение(таймер)

Comment: @Артём кхм, кхм... Это делает код в ответе. Мы с Вами идем по кругу.

Comment: Я понимаю что в ответе есть эти значения. Вот к примеру на странице есть 5 блоков, в ответе 5 значений и как мне их расположить друг к другу

Comment: @Артём В каком ответе какие пять значений?

Comment: На странице загружается 5 блоков с названием и описанием из базы, а в другом файле (в обработчике для аякса) загружается время из базы для таймера, 5 значений времени получится. И как мне обьединить время с блоками